# Issue to save data from a Json in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm a beginner in Objective C and I try to save data from a Json. I did it well, my program take the data from the Json which is on the internet and save it. However when I shutdown the app and launch it again without the internet, It tries to download and save it again instead of load data (I think data had been deleted)

This is my code :

```
- (NSData *)saveAllScheduleData:(NSString *)endpointOfTheChannel {
    NSData *channelData;

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatDuration = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatDuration setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];
    NSDate *duration = [dateFormatDuration dateFromString:@"23:59:59"];
    NSDate *dateOfSave = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"dateOfSave"];
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

    NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
    [calendar components:(NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute | NSCalendarUnitSecond) fromDate:currentDate];

    NSDateComponents *comps = [calendar components:(NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute | NSCalendarUnitSecond) fromDate:duration];
    NSDate *nextSaveDate = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:comps toDate:dateOfSave options:0];

    NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://apis.is%@", endpointOfTheChannel];
    if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey: url] && [currentDate compare:nextSaveDate] == NSOrderedAscending) {
        return channelData = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey: url];
    } else {
        channelData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
        [calendar components:(NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute | NSCalendarUnitSecond) fromDate:dateOfSave];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:dateOfSave forKey:@"dateOfSave"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:channelData forKey:url];
        return channelData;
    }
}
```

Yes I also tried to reload the data each day, but for the moment with that bug, it's useless.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: How are you shutting down the app?

Comment: I double tap on the main button and turn off the app

Comment: you have two conditions in your `if statement`. may be second condition is not fulfilling

Comment: You're right, the second condition is not working well, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two conditions in your `if statement`

May be the second condition is not fulfilling the requirement. (as you confirmed it was not working. So this is the answer)

Secondly When you save any data in `NSUserDefaults` use proper `Keys` to store. You are using a variable `NSString *url` as `Key`. This might be change any time and you would be unable to access `NSUserDefaults` from that `Key`. It may be a constant `key` like you use to save the `dateOfSave`.

Hope you get it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to synchronise the userdefaults with calling

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize]
```

when you save it.